# Sinon fakeserver url regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, unit-testing, sinon

According to the [documentation](http://sinonjs.org/docs/), the Sinon fakeserver can use a regexp pattern to match URLs:

> server.respondWith(method, urlRegExp, response);

I would like to match all URLs that ends with `foo=1`. Here is my attempt:

```
this.server.respondWith('GET', '/foo=1$/', [200, 
{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, '{ "foo": 1 }']);
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. My regexp is probably wrong, but I need your help adjusting it.

http://jsfiddle.net/s38qw3ns/1/

Comment: Have a look at the sample on that site: `server.respondWith(/\/todo-items\/(\d+)/, function (xhr, id) {  xhr.respond(200, { ?Content-Type?: ?application/json? }, ?[{ ?id?: ? + id + ? }]?); });`. There is a `function` that uses `id`, and the `id` is the 1st capturing group in the regex. Perhaps, you need to also capture the group with `/foo=(\d+)/` regex, and use the `id` with the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have single quotes around your regular expression, so sinon is treating it as a string (which it is :).

Get rid of the single quotes and it will be a regular expression and work as you expected.

`this.server.respondWith('GET', /foo=1$/, [200, 
{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, '{ "foo": 1 }']);`

See [Creating a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_regular_expression) on MDN for reference.